# ASP.NET Master Page variable setting/accessing

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page and a child page (page using master page).

I have a class/function that I call from the child page (like this):

```
new MasterPageSiteWide().setGeoAndLanguage(ViewState["_country"].ToString(), _lang);
```

This calls the function (as when I step through it executes the values).

On the master page I have:

```
public partial class MasterPageSiteWide : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string _closeTimeType;
    public string _langForCalendar;

    public void setGeoAndLanguage(string nation, string lang)
    {
        string globalresourcestring = string.Empty;
        _langForCalendar = (String)GetGlobalResourceObject("share", "lblCalendarLang");

        switch (nation.ToUpper())
        {
            case "USA":
                ViewState["geo"] = "USA";
                ViewState["langID"] = 1;
                _closeTimeType = "PTPA";
                break;
            case "CAN":
                if (lang.ToUpper() == "FR")
                {
                    ViewState["geo"] = "CAN";
                    ViewState["langID"] = 2;
                    _closeTimeType = "CANPA";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["geo"] = "CAN";
                    ViewState["langID"] = 1;
                    _closeTimeType = "CANPA";
                }
                break;
            case "MEX":
                ViewState["geo"] = "MEX";
                ViewState["langID"] = 3;
                _closeTimeType = "MEXPA";
                break;
            default:
                ViewState["geo"] = "USA";
                ViewState["langID"] = 1;
                _closeTimeType = "PTPA";
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When the code steps through it sets the variables `_closeTimeType` and `_langForClaendar` (I can see the values).

But when it goes back to the child page those values are `null`.  I am accessing them like this:

```
Master._closeTimeType
```

Also the `ViewState` variables are `null` after the master page is loaded.

**NOTE:**  I do have this line on the `.aspx` page:

```
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPageSiteWide.master"%>
```

Why are the variables not keeping the values I am setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, I think you may be unintentionally instantiating an *additional* master page, when in reality you want to call the functions on the master page upon which the *existing* page instance is based. You might try something akin to the following cast from the child page:

```
((MasterPageSiteWide)this).setGeoAndLanguage(ViewState["_country"].ToString(), _lang);
```

You may also be able to just try it directly, eg

```
Master.setGeoAndLanguage(ViewState["_country"].ToString(), _lang);
```

That should call the master page function from the current page instance, and cause the page to behave as you expect (preserving the values). Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked for the regular variable (YEA), but for the ViewState variables in the function on the master page it sets it but then when the function call finishes the viewstate variable is set back to null when it returns to the main page

Comment: Where is the call to setGeoAndLanguage(...) being made? May be a longshot, but you might need to make a call to the page's TrackViewState() method to ensure .NET is keeping track of the ViewState values you're adding...

Comment: Did a work around for the view state thing but the rest worked thanks!